# Building Atmel START project to load with UF2 bootloader

Tags: embedded, atmel, samd21

I'm trying to build an Atmel START project using GCC such that it will load with the Adafruit UF2 bootloader on a SAMD21 chip.

From prior research I've learned that I need to have the text section start at offset `0x2000`, and I need to specify the same offset to `bossac` when flashing.

I've done both, and confirmed that they are working as intended by reading back the memory but I'm still not able to flash a minimal blinky built using Atmel code.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's too little details to tell. Are you solely relying on some bootloader or do you have an actual in-circuit debugger for flashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue, turns out it was a bug in my code, since I never put a delay after the GPIO write, the LED wasn't turning on. Adding a delay solved the issue.